# How do I make my loop stop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am trying to stop a loop for my calculator program, but I am not allowed to use breaks or system.exit. How would I go so with stopping my loop my just putting in 5 for the menu? Also How do I make the program quit if I would put in "n" for the question asking would I like to use the calculator again? P.S. I am using Java.

```
public static void main (String args []) {
    String MainMenu = " Calculator Options \n\n1. Addition\n2" +
            " Subtraction\n3. Multiplication\n4. Division\n5. Exit";
    menu (MainMenu);

    while (true) {
       String YesorNo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would You Like to Use the Calculator Again (y / n)? ");

       if (YesorNo.equals ("y")) {
           menu (MainMenu);
       }

       if (YesorNo.equals ("n")) {

       }
    }
}

public static int menu (String info) {
    String choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (info);
    if (choice.equals ("1"))
        return Addition();
    else if (choice.equals ("2"))
        return Subtraction();
    else if (choice.equals ("3"))
        return  Multiplication();
    else if (choice.equals ("4"))
        return  Division();
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: use a `do..while` loop which check if `YesorNo.equals ("y")`

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use breaks?

Comment: @Lee my teacher is saying it violates code because it gives two ways out

Comment: @FB10 That "two ways out" principle is outdated.

Comment: @Randumbness he is a old guy :/

Answer (score 2):

Use the `break` keyword.

```
if (YesorNo.equals ("n")) {
    break;
}
```

---

Or place the condition in the `while-loop` and use the keyword `do`.

```
do {
    // code & blaaa .. blaaa & code
} while (YesorNo.equals("y"));
```

Comment: "*but I am not allowed to use breaks*"

Comment: Why the downvote? Anything I can improve or I've missed?

Answer (score 2):

To answer both of you questions:

You simply need to use a `do-while` loop and include both conditions in there.
But With your current implementation that wont be working 100% of the time.

Reason beeing, you return the action aswell as the result from `menu`.

To start of, that´s how your loop could look like.

```
do {
   String YesorNo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Would You Like to Use the Calculator Again (y / n)? ");
   int menuReturn = menu (MainMenu);
} while (YesorNo.equals("y") || menuReturn != 0);
```

That´s what could work, the `menu` method does return `0` if it is not inside the values `0-4`. But what happens when the result of any of your mathemematical operations is `0`? You would also close the calculator. At this point you might want to change what `menu` does.

```
private static int result = 0;

public static int menu (String info) {
   String choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (info);
   if (choice.equals ("1")) {
       result = Addition();
       return 1;
   }
   else if (choice.equals ("2")) {
       result = Subtraction();
       return 1;
   }
   else if (choice.equals ("3")) {
       result = Multiplication();
       return  1;
   }  
   else if (choice.equals ("4")) {
       result = Division();
       return 1;
   }
   else if (choice.equals("5"))
       return -1;
   else 
       return 0;
```

your loop design would change now to something like the following.

```
do {
   String YesorNo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Would You Like to Use the Calculator Again (y / n)? ");
   int menuReturn = menu (MainMenu);
   // Work with the result now
   if (menuReturn == 0) // invalid input;
} while (YesorNo.equals("y") || menuReturn != -1);
```

But in order to make it fully contract the OOP principle you might have to rewrite a little bit more code then shown in the answer.